# How to hide C# application from taskmanager processtab?

Tags: c#, .net, taskmanager, dll-injection, task-management

I need to hide my C# application from process tab of Taskmanager

using

```
this.ShowInTaskbar = false;
```

I have hide it from application tab. Now I need to hide it from process tab.

Is this possible?.

Comment: Any good reasons why you want to do that? Obviously "education purposes" is not the one otherwise you'd read a book about Windows like "Windows Internals"...

Comment: Print it out and put it in a drawer the task manager will never find it there

Comment: +1 Thumb up too, if you think the simple fact of being interested and curious to know more is reason enough to ask.

Answer (score 9):

You could inject a DLL into the svchost process, that would camouflage it from Task Manager but not from ProcessExplorer. Here's how:

[How To Inject a Managed .NET Assembly (DLL) Into Another Process](https://web.archive.org/web/20140625112312/http://codingthewheel.com/archives/how-to-inject-a-managed-assembly-dll/)

Here's some more background info on this technique: [Three Ways to Inject Your Code into Another Process](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/threads/winspy.aspx)

Similar to @Dark Slipstreams link it points unmanaged code info.

Let us know if you have any problems with the code running on Win7?

**Edit:**

*how can i restrict a user while closing my process from taskmanager?* - what exactly are you making here?

I dont care to guess but if you really want to know, you hook into the WinLogon, @Jeff Atwood explains it here: [How to Clean Up a Windows Spyware Infestation](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/06/how-to-clean-up-a-windows-spyware-infestation.html) or you could have 2 processes that both watch each other...

Comment: This won't work from windows vista and up when Microsoft introduced session separation.

Answer (score 4):

If you are trying to prevent your 'standard' users from killing your process you may install your program as Windows Service, run it under special credentials (with non-expiring password in production), setup Automatic startup and allow only 'admins' to kill it.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on why you want to hide it and who you are hiding it from, you may get away with hiding it in plain sight by naming the application something like AdobeUpdater.exe

Comment: but it's able to close from taskamnager.i want to complitly restrict the user.