# How can I hide a console app in Task Manager in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, console-application

I have a console App, I want to hide it from Task Manager while running.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to hide the Console App from App(s) list in Task Manager

Try this :

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace SampleConsoleTest
{
    class Program
    {

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        static extern IntPtr GetConsoleWindow();


        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern bool ShowWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int nCmdShow);


        const int SW_HIDE = 0;
        const int SW_SHOW = 5;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var handle = GetConsoleWindow();


            // Hide
            ShowWindow(handle, SW_HIDE);


            // Show
            //ShowWindow(handle, SW_SHOW);

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

This does not show the app in App List, but is visible in process(s) list.

---

It's about hiding a process from Task Manager.

One of the common approach is injecting process into another : [How to hide C# application from taskmanager processtab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7143541/how-can-i-hide-my-c-sharp-application-from-taskmanager-processtab)

Here is a detailed answer on how you can achieve it : [How do I hide a process in Task Manager in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/187983/how-do-i-hide-a-process-in-task-manager-in-c)

Comment: it is not a process !

Comment: Every running program is a process...

Comment: @Amirdo u mean to hide the console application from App(s) list in task manager ?

Comment: @PaRiMaLRaJ : Yes, Thank you.